# Catch a warning using plpgsql

Tags: postgresql, exception, error-handling, warnings, plpgsql

I'm trying to handle a warning but I read in the documentation that you cannot do it in plpgsql.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_team(person varchar(50), id_team integer, long varchar(50), short varchar(25)) RETURNS VOID AS $$
   BEGIN
       PERFORM * FROM team WHERE id = id_team;
     IF FOUND THEN
       UPDATE team SET long_name = long WHERE id = id_team;
       UPDATE team SET short_name = short WHERE id = id_team;
       RAISE INFO 'Team update.';
     ELSE
       RAISE INFO 'Cannot find team id';
   END IF;

  EXCEPTION
   WHEN privilege_not_granted THEN
     RAISE INFO 'Cannot do that';
 END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And of course it is not working. I get the error:

> Error: ERROR:  unrecognized exception condition "privilege_not_granted"
>   CONTEXT:  compilation of PL/pgSQL function "update_team" near line 12

I need to catch and handle this warning when some user does not have the privilege on a table.

Comment: I think you want `insufficient_privilege` instead of `privilege_not_granted`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really cannot to catch warnings - there is not any mechanism how to do it. Exceptions are different creatures. The error message is clean, you can try some what is not a exception. The names (and codes) of available exceptions are in this [list](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/errcodes-appendix.html).

What exception you should to catch you can find with following steps:

```
postgres=# create role student login;
CREATE ROLE
postgres=# create table foo(a int);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# set role to student;
SET
postgres=> \set VERBOSITY verbose 
postgres=> update foo set a = 20;
ERROR:  42501: permission denied for table foo
LOCATION:  aclcheck_error, aclchk.c:3487
```

So you should to handle a exception with code `42501`, and in mentioned document with list of exceptions you can find a name `insufficient_privilege` (what was mentioned by @nick-barnes before)